# Unique customers who received 1, 2, or emails

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I'm trying to find the count of unique customers who received 1/2/3 emails from the table below:

| cust_id | month | email_cnt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 202311 | 1 |
| 1 | 202311 | 1 |
| 1 | 202310 | 1 |
| 1 | 202310 | 0 |
| 1 | 202309 | 1 |
| 2 | 202311 | 0 |
| 2 | 202311 | 0 |
| 2 | 202310 | 0 |
| 2 | 202310 | 1 |
| 2 | 202309 | 1 |
| 3 | 202311 | 0 |
| 3 | 202311 | 1 |
| 3 | 202310 | 0 |
| 3 | 202310 | 0 |
| 3 | 202309 | 1 |

This is the desired output, after summing the # of emails per month, count the number of unique customers who received x number of emails:

| month | cust_with_1email | cust_with_2email | cust_with_3email |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 202311 | 2 | 1 | 0 |
| 202310 | 2 | 0 | 0 |
| 202309 | 3 | 0 | 0 |

I'm trying to use a CASE function without success:

```
SELECT distinct month, 
SUM(case when email_cnt = 1 then email_cnt end) cust_with_1email, 
SUM(case when email_cnt = 2 then email_cnt end) cust_with_2email, 
SUM(case when email_cnt = 3 then email_cnt end) cust_with_3email
FROM mytable
GROUP BY month
```

Comment: use '`GROUP BY month`

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to paste that here. The issue still persists as my query doesn't sum the number of emails to be captured in the cust_with_2email and cust_with_3email columns.

Comment: i can not reproduce your result how do you get 1 on 202311 and cust_with_2email

Comment: There is only one customer (cust_id=1) that had two emails sent in 202311. Cust 2 had zero and cust 3 had only 1 email sent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i can't still not reproduce your result.

But

```
WITH CTE as (SELECT
cust_id, month, SUM(email_cnt) email_cnt
FROM mytable
GROUP BY cust_id, month)
SELECT month, 
SUM(case when email_cnt = 1 then email_cnt ELSE 0 end) cust_with_1email, 
SUM(case when email_cnt = 2 then email_cnt ELSE 0  end) cust_with_2email, 
SUM(case when email_cnt = 3 then email_cnt ELSE 0  end) cust_with_3email
FROM CTE
GROUP BY month
```

| month | cust_with_1email | cust_with_2email | cust_with_3email |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 202311 | 1 | 2 | 0 |
| 202310 | 2 | 0 | 0 |
| 202309 | 3 | 0 | 0 |

Will give you at least a deterministic result

Comment: This works, thank you! Having a CTE with the sum of emails is what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT 
    email_sum, 
    COUNT(*) AS unique_customer_count
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         cust_id, 
         SUM(email_cnt) AS email_sum
     FROM customer_emails
     GROUP BY cust_id) AS sum_table
WHERE email_sum IN (1, 2, 3)
GROUP BY email_sum;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use below approach

```
select * from (
  select month, sum(email_cnt) as email_cnt
  from your_table
  group by month, cust_id
)
pivot (sum(email_cnt) as email_cnt_ for email_cnt in (1,2,3))
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can add a first 'layer' (a CTE in my example) to aggregate email counts by month and customer, then produce your results:

```
With YrTbl as (
select *
from (
values 
 (1,202311,1)
,(1,202311,1)
,(1,202310,1)
,(1,202310,0)
,(1,202309,1)
,(2,202311,0)
,(2,202311,0)
,(2,202310,0)
,(2,202310,1)
,(2,202309,1)
,(3,202311,0)
,(3,202311,1)
,(3,202310,0)
,(3,202310,0)
,(3,202309,1)
) T(cust_id, mnth, email_cnt)
),
AggregateEMails as (
select 
    mnth
  , cust_id
  , sum(email_cnt) as email_cnt_mth
from YrTbl
group by 
   mnth
 , cust_id
)
select 
   mnth
 , count(case when email_cnt_mth = 1 then cust_id end) as cust_with_1email
 , count(case when email_cnt_mth = 2 then cust_id end) as cust_with_2email
 , count(case when email_cnt_mth = 3 then cust_id end) as cust_with_3email
from AggregateEMails
group by 
    mnth
```